# Ext HDD recognised in Device Manager but not accessible

Tags: windows-7, usb, external-hard-drive

I've got an external HDD connected using a dock and USB2 to a WIN 7 laptop.

[image]

The docked HDD was previously used on Mac systems without an issue, and I can only assume it was formatted suitably. I was not the one who handled it so I'm not sure.

Now when I hook it up, I can see the driver has been installed successfully, the device appears in Device Manager, I can hear and feel the disc spinning, but it's not accessible and doesn't appear on My Computer

[image]

My question is, how do I find out what's wrong with it, or alternatively: is there some 'back-door' way to format it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you assigned a drive letter? -> Open the Disk-Management [over Windows 7 » Start Button "Start" or » "Run..." and type in » Perform (Edit-Box) "diskmgmt.msc" [ENTER] or just click OK] and have a look at your Disk (2, 3 or what number it is). If you are in doubt take it out from the dock and plug-in again until you are sure about the number. Then right click the partition from the Disk and with "Change Drive Letter and Paths", "Add...", "Assign..." a drive letter.
Also the Disk-Management can format the drive for you if you really want this. Before that you can read it with HfsExplorer: http://download.cnet.com/HFSExplorer/3000-2248_4-75793027.html and backup what it is important for you.

Comment: Hey, so I tried what you suggested, but when I right click on the partition I can't press on anything other than "Delete Volume". What does this mean?

Comment: for more help see http://www.winability.com/delete-protected-efi-disk-partition/